# Enabling Download prerequisites from the same location as my application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, prerequisites

I currently have a winforms app that is deployed via clickonce deployment. When I try to deploy it from 1 machine it throws the following error:

> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my
>   application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file
>   'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64es.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine. For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.

The applicacion I'm trying to deploy has Spanish as its Publish Language, therefore it tries to download the language pack (dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64es.exe)

I did download the files necessary as the link in the error suggest but the problem persists. 
I added the files as suggested in the error link to the folder %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages (for Visual Studio 2010). I also tried to add them to %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages (for Visual Studio 2012)

This problem started when I installed Visual Studio 2012 on my machine. I now have Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 installed side by side on Windows 7 Professional (64-bit). It was working fine before. It's also working fine on another machine that doesn't have Visual Studio 2012 installed.

I tried to publish the app with Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 and none work. Also, if I change the language to English, it publishes fine.

Uninstalling Visual Studio 2012 and publishing in English are not valid options.

Any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/05cb5b29-b8be-4877-9aaa-8047697b7bf0) in which some similar problem is attacked. It doesn't have anything to do with VS 2010 and 2012 side by side installation. I had to add the language file installer to the appropriate language folder, NOT the root folder as other links suggest.

Comment: Yes - this works. If you are not copying in files that are language dependent then they just go into the root bootstrap package folder.

Answer (score 3):

**Vs 2013 targetting Dot net 4.5 64 bit will have here**

the path in registry is HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0 for Vs 2013 targeting dot net 4.5

value will be `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`

Answer (score 3):

Correct paths are these,

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages on a 32-bit system

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages on a 64-bit system.

Other suggested ones didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Here an alternative](http://www.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&tl=en&u=http://codigosevero.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/al-generar-un-proyecto-de-instalacion-aparece-el-error-to-enable-download-prerequisites-from-the-same-location-as-my-application-in-the-prerequisites-dialog-box-y-luego-un-paquete-en-particu/&sandbox=1), is in Spanish, but it could well serve as this quite clear.